# How to install and run insiders' Linux rpm?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the procedure for installing and then running the insiders' rpm for Linux (I'm running Fedora 22) ?

Best regards
David

Comment: This was a pretty trivial search. https://code.visualstudio.com/Download#insiders
Do tell what you have tried and the problems that you have encountered.

Comment: I had found that page, but there's nothing there about how to install it (I guess sudo rpm -ivh <rpm>) or how to run it when it's installed (just 'code' ?).

Comment: I suppose that you are a regular Fedora user. You should have tried installing it and running it as a regular RPM package before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation isn't out/finalized yet since it's the Insiders build. [You can read the WIP instructions here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/setup.md#linux). These will eventually be located at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/setup#_linux

For the rpm file try:

```
sudo yum install <file>.rpm
```

That may advise you to use `dnf` which is just a matter of changing `yum` to `dnf`:

```
sudo dnf install <file>.rpm
```

The package installs a bin command `code-insiders` as well as a desktop entry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.